Phpstorm built-in webserver isn't working (404 error)
The built-in webserver in phpstorm isn't working for some reasons. I get the 404 error. PHP itself is installed and working on the Built-in Preview or even on my own used browser(s).
I hope the pictures say enough and would also like to add that when I added the CLI interpreter, specifically the configuration file, I renamed the file “php.ini-development” to “php.ini”. Just wanted to note this, I have no idea whether it is relevant.






So.. are you trying to use a Run/Debug Configuration of "PHP Built-in Web Server" type using the same 63342 port as PhpStorm's built-in simple web server uses? Am I correct in interpreting your screenshots?

Yes, but other ports don't work as well. I just thought using especially the same port would work because the built-in simple web server uses it and it works. I just edited and added a picture of how it looks like when I try port 80 for example.

You cannot use the same port that built-in webserver uses. Simply because it is already used by the IDE (one port/server for ALL projects) and you cannot run another server on the same port.

BTW -- this is what PHP built-in webserver is -- the docs from PHP website: https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php Make sure you have files that you are requesting (at the right path).

Please specify the paths used (the issue must be in them). 1) The project root path 2) The website root path that you have specific for your Run/Debug Configuration. From what I see from your screenshots, the "Document root" is most likely points to the Project Root folder, and according to the latest screenshot with the web server logs -- browser asks for the index / and then /favicon.ico.

At the same time -- from your first screenshot (that shows the Project View panel), I see only 3 folders in the project root -- no index.php or favicon.ico there. They could be in a subfolder. If that's the case -- use the correct path for the "Document root" in your Run/Debug Configuration. For me (based on screenshots only), it's a user misconfiguration error.

You mention using your browser, so this detail from the documentation may be relevant:

For security reasons, any request to a page on the built-in server
from outside PhpStorm is by default rejected and a Page 404 is
displayed.
To allow access to the requested page, select the Allow unsigned
requests checkbox.

Once you have set that, I'd suggest making a basic html page (for example \test.html) and verify that you can access that before moving on to serving php files.
